# I need to create a function vector from 3 function vectors I've previously created . below is what I have done

Tags: r, vector

Here are the vectors I created originally :

Vector 1

```
vmn<- function() {
    x <- sample(1:20, 5, replace = FALSE)
    return (x)
}
```

Vector 2

```
vma <- function(){
    x <- letters[1:26] 
    y <- sample(x, 5, replace=FALSE) 
    return(y)
}
```

Vector 3

```
vector.maker.bool <- function() {
    x <- c((1:20), (1:10 ==TRUE))
    z <- as.logical(sample(x, 5, replace=FALSE)) 
    return(z) 
}
```

This is what need to get: I have to modify the 3 vectors creating functions into one function vector maker with all 3.

1. When you call it, it randomly returns either a numeric, character, or logical vector.
2. Still have an optional argument for length of returned vector
3. BUT, if length not specified length should be RANDOM between 5 and 10.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
Vector.Maker.Mod <- function() {  
    a <- function(ls) {  
        x<- c(1:20)
        sample(x, len, replace = FALSE)  
        return (x)
    }   
    function() {
        x <- letters[1:26]   
        y  <- sample(x, len, replace=FALSE)   
        return(y)
    }
    function() {    
        x = c(TRUE,FALSE )    
        return(sample(x, len, replace=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `}` at the end.  Is that a copy/paste issue or could that be the problem?

Comment: I had the extre} but whenever I tried to run it I got ann error: unexpected "}" in return 9x)}

Comment: You need to describe in greater detail what is being attempted. 
 Saying "didn't return expected output" is not helpful. Placing three functions, the last two being anonymous, inside that last function is only going to return a single anonymous function. You also need to describe how you intend to use it.

Comment: or at least show us an example of the desired output

Comment: It did not work at all  got an error message and  error no function to return from , jumping to top level

Comment: are you stuck with an open bracket from a previous attempt?  Make sure you're starting from a clean R session.

Comment: Thank, I m still a little lost . I am "pre-novice " in R and I got  an assignment that is to modify 3 existing vectors , one logical, one numeric and one  char.  using the 3 vectors functions I created earlier. I am pretty sure that all have to have the same length

Comment: . on this assignment  this assignment I had to modify the 3 vectors creating functions  into one function vector maker with all 3.  : 1) When you call it, it randomly returns either a numeric, character, or logical vector.
2) Still have an optional argument for length of returned vector
3) BUT, if length not specified length should be RANDOM between 5 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having trouble with leftover open-brackets from previous attempts. Try starting from a clean R session ... Something like this should work.

```
Vector.Maker.Mod <- function() {
  list(num=function(len) {
         return(sample(1:20,len,replace = FALSE))
       },
       alph=function(len) {
         return(sample(letters,len, replace=FALSE))
       },
       bool=function(len) {
          return(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), len, replace=TRUE))
       }
   ) ## end list
} ## end factory function

vv <- Vector.Maker.Mod()
vv$num(5)
```

... note that the `num` and `alph` function will only work with appropriate `len` values (<=20 and <=26 respectively) since you've specified `replace=FALSE` in those cases.

Comment: Hi Thank you all. Sorry I am very very new to R . Kind of kindergarten  level . on this assignment IO had to modify the 3 vector creation functions  into one function vector maker. and :

Comment: sorry my comment got  cut , here it is Hi Thank you all. Sorry I am very very new to R . Kind of kindergarten  level . on this assignment  this assignment I had to modify the 3 vectors creating functions  into one function vector maker with all 3.  : 1) When you call it, it randomly returns either a numeric, character, or logical vector.
2) Still have an optional argument for length of returned vector
3) BUT, if length not specified length should be RANDOM between 5 and 10.